# No Access .. field was removed from the entity or access to this field was removed e.force:createRecord

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

In my controller I populate a map with the record type id:

```
         ...
            String myrec = 
             GetRecordType.getDefaultRecordTypeID('Waste_Assessment__c');
            fields.put('rectypeid',myrec);
       }
    return fields;
```

then I fire a create event with e.force:createRecord

```
       var createWA = $A.get('e.force:createRecord');
        console.log('2rec type id: '+fields['rectypeid']);
        var recTYPEID = fields['rectypeid'];
        createWA.setParams({
            "entityApiName":"Waste_Assessment__c",
            "recordTypeId": recTYPEID,
            "defaultFieldValues":fields
        });
        createWA.fire();
```

the new record window appears but when I try to save I get:

> No access to field rectypeid. Either the field was removed from the entity or access to this field was removed.
>   [image]

What's going on ?

Comment: Do you receive the same error if you don't use the record type? Not sure but this could be related to this [known issue](https://sforce.co/2U5MdMk).

Comment: I saw that before too, and yea I still get the message, which is weird because the message mentions my variable name. How could it know if I've commented it out of the setParams() list

Comment: And yea I see the recordtypid in console.log() just fine.

Comment: Ah i think it's because I am passing that same map to the default fields option!

Comment: Are you able to resolve it? I am getting the same error.

Comment: @sfdc rowdy Yea delete that property from `fields`

Comment: @SallyRothroat - Can you please explain a bit?

Answer (score 2):

Replace recordTypeId by RecordTypeId because its case sensitive :

createWA.setParams({
        "entityApiName":"Waste_Assessment__c",
        "RecordTypeId": recTYPEID,
        "defaultFieldValues":fields
    });

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by removing the property that was causing the error:

```
    var createWA = $A.get('e.force:createRecord');
    console.log('2rec type id: '+fields['rectypeid']);
    var recTYPEID = fields['rectypeid'];

   //remove prop
   delete fields['rectypeid'];       


    createWA.setParams({
        "entityApiName":"Waste_Assessment__c",
        "recordTypeId": recTYPEID,
        "defaultFieldValues":fields
    });
    createWA.fire();
```