# No Access to field Stage. Either field was removed from the entity or access to this field was removed

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I know there's an [identical question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/254814/no-access-field-was-removed-from-the-entity-or-access-to-this-field-was-remov/267363) but the way it was solved worked for me at first but know almost a month later the error came back even though the field is still removed from the defaultFieldValues

Again I removed the Stage field which was the one giving me the problem, test it out and worked fine that day, a month later a user had to use it again and now is failing exactly the same even though the field is not there.

Original Code:

```
 if(createRecordEvent){ //checking if the event is supported
        if(recordTypeId){//if recordTypeId is supplied, then set recordTypeId parameter
            createRecordEvent.setParams({
                "entityApiName": entityApiName,
                "recordTypeId": recordTypeId,
                "defaultFieldValues": {
                    "AccountId": component.get("v.recordId"),  
                    "Stage": "Posted",
                    "CloseDate" :today,
                    "Name": component.get("v.acc.Name") + ' - '+ today  
                }
            });
```

How it is now but failing again:

```
 if(createRecordEvent){ //checking if the event is supported
        if(recordTypeId){//if recordTypeId is supplied, then set recordTypeId parameter
            createRecordEvent.setParams({
                "entityApiName": entityApiName,
                "recordTypeId": recordTypeId,
                "defaultFieldValues": {
                    "AccountId": component.get("v.recordId"),  
                    "CloseDate" :today,
                    "Name": component.get("v.acc.Name") + ' - '+ today  
                }
            });
```

Please I need help in fixing this

Comment: If this is an Opportunity, then the API name is `StageName`, not `Stage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks cropredy, that is correct, I did also try with that however my actual mistake was that I was looking at the wrong code, since the error message was the same as the last time the client told me but it was actually being called from a different object so the solution was to remove it from the line like the first time is just I was looking at the wrong Helper this time.